# wp_insert_post with existing categories/terms

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I am inserting posts from one CPT to another, using `wp_insert_post`and hooking to `add_action('wp', 'function_name')`

How do I successfully insert the new posts with the terms/categories (e.g "type 1") "ticked" upon creation? The main purpose is to have a friendly URL such as `domain_name/cat1/cat2/post_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the funcion [wp_set_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term, $taxonomy );
```

Notes from documentation :

```
$tag = '5'; // Wrong. This will add the tag with the *name* '5'.
$tag = 5; // Wrong. This will also add the tag with the name '5'.
$tag = array( '5' ); // Wrong. Again, this will be interpreted as a term name rather than an id.

$tag = array( 5 ); // Correct. This will add the tag with the id 5.
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to change my approach to the entire thing - making it more simple for the user. - https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/